# How to add extra data to a ui:button in a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I have several buttons which I need to assign to the same handler, but each one will act on a different value.  I would LIKE to do something like the code at the end of this post, but I cannot find a way to do it.

I have tried using HTML5 data- tags (per the discussion [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005GGnIAM)), but that discussion seems to operate on raw HTML tags, and when I try adding a data- tag to a `<ui:button>` element, I get an error like the following: `Error: The attribute "data-extraValue" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://ui:button`

Does anyone know of any way to pass small bits of data to the controller without resorting to something weird like writing a custom component to house each of the buttons?

---

## Example code (what I would *like* to do):

### Component

```
<ui:button label="Button A" extraValue="A" press="{!c.handlerFunction}"/>
<ui:button label="Button B" extraValue="B" press="{!c.handlerFunction}"/>
<ui:button label="Button C" extraValue="C" press="{!c.handlerFunction}"/>
```

### Controller

```
({
    handlerFunction : function(cmp, evt) {
        var extraVal;
        //  somehow lookup extraValue field from the clicked button
        console.log('extraValue was: '+extraVal);
    }
})
```

Comment: why not use HTML button tag instead `ui:button`?

Comment: @Praveen: I could try that, but I tend to stick to the framework's native elements when possible, in case there is anything which Lightning does to normalize elements/events across devices (mobile/tablet/desktop).  I assumed there must be some way to do it with native <ui:button> elements.

Comment: Good instincts there - if you use native elements, things get a lot harder and you run into LockerService problems.

Comment: @CasparHarmer:  What are "LockerService" problems?  EDIT:  Disregard.  I should use Google BEFORE asking dumb questions.  ;-)

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot use attributes that aren't part of the `ui:button` component.

Comment: I'm considering using the following approach, and stuffing my IDs into the aura:id attribute.  That seems like an abuse of aura:id though.  :-\  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just extend `ui:button` and add an attribute. Eg,

```
<!--<c:myNewUIButton>-->
<aura:component extends="ui:button">
    <aura:attribute name="someAttribute"  type="string" />
</aura:component>
```

Then you should be able to use that attribute when you use the new component

```
<c:myNewUIButton someAttribute="blah" press="{!c.doSomething}"/>
```

Comment: @loneboat I believe the above answer will surely solve your problem.Please mark it as accepted if it helps.

Comment: @Praveen: Done.  Thanks both of you for your help!

Comment: I was going to suggest this but - playing with it in my Dev Console, I run into a problem. In the button press handler, if I try to call `event.getSource()` it throws an uncaught exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: addHandler(…)`. I am guessing this is a Locker issue. So you can extend the component but you can't get a reference to it from the handler nor obtain the data.

Comment: Sounds like that's a bug that needs fixing. A child component should be able to access it's parent's public properties. So no other way of fixing this? @Doug Chasman ?

Comment: It's not even that the child can't access its parent... it's that if you have an instance of the subcomponent and pass in a handler for an event of the supercomponent, the handler cannot get the source of the event - it's not finding the sub **nor** the super.

Comment: Yes, good point. It definitely needs to be able to access that - otherwise why would you extend anything.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution will not solve your problem at the moment if Lightning Locker is enabled. In the button press handler, if I try to call `event.getSource()` it throws an uncaught exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: addHandler(…)`. I am guessing this is a Locker issue. So you can extend the component but you can't get a reference to it from the handler nor obtain the data.

For what it's worth, there are other `ui:button` attributes you could abuse instead of `aura:id`. You could stuff information into `class` or `labelClass`, and those will just be extraneous CSS styles that don't do anything.

Comment: Hopefully by the time Lightning Locker is mandatory, this will be fixed...

Comment: Indeed. The inability to pass arbitrary parameters in handlers makes us very reliant on what we can retrieve from the `event` object.

Answer (score 0):

Going forward, I don't think this is possible without creating your own button in some way. Their are two solutions their:
1) create your own version of ui:button in the your own namespace
2) go strait to a  rather then a component.
Both of these ways of pluses and minus.

Our solutions is that instead of extending the ui:button we simply copy the code from the ui:button component into a c:button (our own version) that we could then extend into c:awesomebutton. The combination of locker service plus the ui objects not reproducing Lightning Design system complaint html (mainly because they contain their own css beyond the attribute css classes) has caused us to pull in the source from the Aura repository to then modify. This is clearly not a good or clean solution but its working. If desired we can post a repository with all of our extended/SLDS targeted objects.

Comment: I have not had any success copying their source code. Maybe there are things I'm missing, but it seems that the markup uses private methods/interfaces/components that custom components don't have access to. And even when we are able to copy enough things to get their code working, their components still get to run in the system context while ours run in Locker.

Comment: But might I add, if you have a customized version of `ui:inputDate` that complies with SLDS I would love to see it.

Comment: I would add that we've made at this point we've made a decent number for revisions to ensure locker compatibility.  Personally,  I believe that there is no reason why the provide UI would need to run in System Context to function. If they do then it would be more a problem with the framework.  UI:inputDate is not one we have 100% (mainly we have not been able to replicate the Datepicker functionality without a provider). I find it striking that the UI:inputDate datepicker looks so different then Design System. This is one we find the reference has significantly more functionality as well.

Comment: Haha, yes, I'd be keen to see an input date in the wild too... ;)